# how to run the jobs queue immediately after a job added to queue in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I currently registered `php artisan schedule:run` in cronjob in cpanel and the schedule method is:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')
    ->cron('* * * * *')
    ->withoutOverlapping(5);
}
```

But for my purpose it is necessary to run the jobs immediately,

How can I run `php artisan queue:work` immediately after a job added to queue(jobs table) and not after one minute?

Comment: launch the queue as a cron job without stopping it.

Comment: in that case, Physical Memory Usage goes to 100% and give error of allocate memory.

Comment: so you have a memory leak if stopping the queue fixes it. Correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to call `queue:work` on destruct() method of each class that I want to run it's job immediately.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ProductShopObserver implements ShouldQueue
{
     public function __destruct()
     {
         Artisan::call('queue:work --stop-when-empty');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel > 7.x  We can dispatch anonymosly

```
use App\Mail\WelcomeMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
 
dispatch(function () {
    Mail::to('taylor@laravel.com')->send(new WelcomeMessage);
})->afterResponse();
```

The `WelcomeMessage` should implement/use `Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;`

For Laravel 6.x
Instead of dispatching a job class to the queue, you may also dispatch a Closure. This is great for quick, simple tasks that need to be executed outside of the current request cycle:

```
$podcast = App\Podcast::find(1);
 
dispatch(function () use ($podcast) {
    $podcast->publish();
});
```

for more you can read laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues